# (How) can two words differ in fewer places than the minimum distance?

Tags: cryptography, reed-muller-codes, question-verification

I'm working on an unassessed course problem (which I paraphrase for conciseness),

> Let $C$ be the code over $\mathbb{F}_5$ with generator and parity-check matrices
> $$G=\begin{pmatrix}2&3&4&1\end{pmatrix}, \hspace{1em} H=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&3\\2&1&0&3\\0&1&1&3\end{pmatrix}.$$
> Determine the minimum distance $d(C)$ and the error-correcting index $t$,
> and find the codeword of $C$ closest to $\underline{w}=1123$.

The solution booklet gives $$d=4, \hspace{1em} t=1, \hspace{1em} \underline{c}=1423 \text{ with } d(\underline{w},\underline{c})=1.$$

How can two words differ in fewer places than the minimum distance?
I'm guessing there's something basic I haven't understood.

Comment: The minimum distance of a code is the minimum distance between two codewords.  Which need not be the distance between a codeword and a non-codeword.

Comment: @kimchilover OK, thanks, that makes sense. It didn't occur to me that $\underline{w}\notin C$. The comment is enough for me, but if you want to make it an answer I'll be happy to accept.

Comment: @kimchilover is right. also what makes a code able to correct errors is that non-codewords $w$ which are at most distance $t$ from a codeword, where $d=2t+1$ or $d=2t+2$ can be decoded to the nearest codeword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my intuitive way to see what is going on here.

Let us say , we have some way to put the Code Points in some linear order (which is not generally true : the "order" will be in some non-linear graph , but that is enough to see the intuition behind the Issue here)

[image: CODE POINTS]

Here the Integer Code Points are the Blue Marks , which may be something like $1423$.
The other Integer Points on the line are invalid Code Patterns. Eg the Purple Mark & the Green Mark , which may be like $1123$.

Over-all , the Minimum Distance is between 2 Blue Marks which is highlighted with the Arrows.

Now , we are given 2 invalid Integer Points , the Purple Mark & the Green Mark.
We want to know which valid Code Point got transmitted with errors , hence we chose the left Code Point for Purple Mark & the right Code Point for the Green Mark , because these are the closest valid Code Points to those invalid Points.

It might happen that the errors are too large & the transmitted Purple Point was actually the left-most & the transmitted Green Point was actually the right-most , though we will not know that : We will always select the nearest unique Blue Mark.

Now , we see that :
(1) the Distance between Valid Code Points is very large
(2) these Distances between Valid Code Points have a Minimum (larger is better)
(3) the Distance between valid Mark & Invalid Mark might be less (smaller is better)
(4) In fact , Distance between valid Mark & Invalid Mark SHOULD BE less than Minimum Distance between valid Code Points , to allow selecting the Correct Code Point when receiving invalid Core Points with errors

In text  book Exercise , we received $1123$ which is invalid.
We calculate that the Original Code Point must have been $1423$ because that is the nearest , with Distance $1$.
Luckily , the error during transmission did not exceed $4$ , which is the Minimum Distance between 2 valid Code Points.
In Case , the error Distance had been 2 , we might have 2 or more valid Code Points to select (something like left-nearest , right-nearest , upper-nearest or lower-nearest) : we will not know which was the Original Code Point.